# in app billing :- Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am implementing app billing in my app. I have tried all the possible solutions on the stack over flow , but I am unable to succeed in what I tried. I have updated all the api keys and created product items with ids in the dev console, and I have uploaded my singed apk to my alpha but not published ,only I have saved in the drafts. And I have created tester accounts to test the app.

When I am testing in all the accounts i got the same error

Please help me to get out this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to publish app to [test IAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082402/in-app-billing-authentication-is-required-you-need-to-sign-into-your-google/34084861#34084861). You can test even being on alpha channel.

> To test in-app billing, you need to publish your app to an alpha or
>   beta channel in Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

to able test google IAP android, you must change your app to production or beta testing mode

Likes this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you mean ,if it is in alpha , we are unable to get the IAB services...?

Comment: I am not try, i only use beta teing and production mode to test. i think aslo work on alpha testing mode